# Cross correlation using photographic film

Tags: cross-correlation, history

I used to work for a guy who told me about working for an oil company, probably in the 1960's, doing cross correlation work by sliding two pieces of developed film strips across each other (maybe they were seismic traces, purty sure), shining light through them both and photographing the results onto another strip of film.  Something like that!  I'm sure I've misunderstood a few key points, because I'm not sure how that would work.  Has anybody heard of that sort of thing?  I'd love to have some info on what folks did in the early cross correlation work.

Comment: If you have two series as a function of time, where time was over the same interval & in the same units (eg, 1 cm = 1 month), this could be just a quick & dirty way to visualize different lags.

Comment: @gung - yes, that's it.  The seismic traces are a film strip with wiggles on them.  I think the idea would be to have a wiggle trace from a known oil reservoir and compare it with a trace recorded nearby to see if they correlate well.  (This question is based on the application of seismic surveys to oil/gas exploration.). I find the history of cross correlation applications To seismic processing and interpretation interesting - I'm researching it now and will post if I get a good handle on it: it's an interesting historical application of analog cross correlation in the days before digital.